# IAP accepts expired token in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, identity-aware-proxy

After following [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_from_a_desktop_app) on generating token programmatically. We found that IAP was allowing tokens even when they expired.

We were expecting 401 response if an expired token was passed as a bearer token for authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting in touch with support team from GCP, we found that simply changing a url param value should fix the following issue as the generated token is tied to the GCP user session when the token is generated in a normal login flow, but however this should not be the case when trying to generate the token programmatically as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/sessions-howto#session_expiration).

To fix this, change the query param 'cred_ref' value to false when trying to generate CODE in step 3 of [signing in to the application](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#signing_in_to_the_application) documentation. So, the correct URI to get the CODE should be:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=DESKTOP_CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&scope=openid%20email&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&cred_ref=false
```

After generating CODE using above modified URI, fetch a new ID token. But now the token after expiring should return a 401 error instead of just accepting the expired token.